# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 or 2016 Feature

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I remember that, I read in some blog or page that there is a interesting feature in SQL Server 2014/2016 that It captures the Workload of Production and we can use the captured workload for our testing purposes in testing environment. For sure It is not profiler. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that you are refereeing to the [Distributed Replay Client and Distributed Replay Coordinator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878183.aspx). These components were available in in the 2014 SQL Server setup.